# In Store Delivery sources show regardless of product stock status

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, shipping-methods, instore-pickup

I have come across an issue in Magento 2.4.6 p3 that appears to be a bug, https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37992

When using the In Store Delivery option if a product is out of stock you would expect the collection point not to be available but it still shows at checkout.

I have tried using the suggested fix by one of the users but I cant get it to work

```
GetPickupLocationIntersectionForSkus.php
->where(SourceItemInterface::STATUS . ' = 1')
```

I am trying to find a work around if anyone has come across it before

Edit:

The above would work if there if there is only one pickup location